# Creating a Masonry grid in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, grid, wpbakery

I am looking to implement a masonry grid on the homepage of my website that incorporates 4 images.

There are 2 rectangular images and 2 square images but I want to put them together so they fit into a nice grid.

I have attached an image to show you below.

I am building my website in Wordpress using WPBakery page builder but I can't seem to find a way to achieve what I am looking for.

Are there any other plugins which might help me?
What is the best way for me to achieve this?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CSS grid which gives you this :

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
        grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
}

.box {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x400);
    grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
 }

.b {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x200);
    grid-column:  2 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.c {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
 }

 .d {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box a">A</div>
      <div class="box b">B</div>
      <div class="box c">C</div>
      <div class="box d">D</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall try this solution as I can just add the custom HTML/CSS to the wordpress page

Comment: This solution works great for Chrome, Edge and Safari but does not work in IE11. Instead of using the grid it stacks the content putting the boxes below each other in 4 separate rows. It might be in the grid properties? How can I get around this? Its pretty much a game breaker for older browers

Comment: Edge is the new browser for MS and fully supports display: grid. If you want to support I.E, you will need to add your own CSS.